# angular, do stuff after ng-show

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-scope

Im populating my page from my angular controller (with ajax) and using ng-show to show stuff in certain steps.
The problem is that I need to resize the height of the background after ng-show has shown the elements. How do I do that?

The function in the controller looks something like this

```
$scope.showProducts = function () {

    $http({ method: 'GET', url: 'myUrl' }).
        success(function(data) {

           $scope.productVisible = true;

           $scope.products= data;

          //here i would like to recalculate the height of the document but it hasn't shown the products yet
    });

};
```

The html like this:

```
            <li ng-repeat="product in products" ng-show="productVisible">
                {{product.ProductName}}
            </li>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `watch` to subscribe to the change as it gets reflected:

```
    $scope.$watch('productVisible', function (newVal, oldVal) {

    if(newVal){
        //Change height here
    }

    }, true);
```

Answer (score 0):

ng-show executes at priority 0 so you could create a custom directive with negative priority and place it on the same element - this way it will execute as the last one.

Comment: ok, how is that done? I tried to google it but it seems like a huge topic (I just started with angular)

Comment: You can take a look at http://www.bennadel.com/blog/2592-hooking-into-the-complete-event-of-an-ngrepeat-loop-in-angularjs.htm?utm_content=bufferf30e8&utm_medium=social&utm_source=twitter.com&utm_campaign=buffer where is explained the creation of a directive with a specific priority.